# CloudApp Client?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-sharing

I like the concept of [CloudApp](http://getcloudapp.com), and I was wondering if there was a native client, or another service with similar functionality that **is not** Dropbox or Ubuntu One.

Requirements:

Drag 'n drop for file uploading,

Wishlist:

It automatically copies the URL to the clipboard.

Comment: "Automatically coping the URL (to the shared file) to the clipboard." is a killer feature. Is there anything with this functionality on Ubuntu?

Comment: http://support.getcloudapp.com/discussions/help/389-cloudapp-and-ubuntu - the CloudApp team is going to develop a client that could work on Ubuntu

Comment: @Jeznet 1. Yes there is. `xclip` does that quite nicely. And add that as an answer, and I'll accept it unless I find anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Found it](https://github.com/abhinandh/py-cloudapp).

To get it working, you need to clone the repository. In order to do that, you need to install `git-core` - and while we're at it, we'll install the dependencies. to do that, run the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install git-core python-qt4`

Once `git-core` is installed, run the following:

`git clone https://github.com/abhinandh/py-cloudapp`

`cd py-cloudapp`

`python ./cloudapp&`

There you go! You can now safely close the terminal. It'll continue running. Enter in your username/password for cloudapp, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the most basic functionality (i.e. upload screenshots to CloudApp and share them), I wrote a [CloudApp](http://getcloudapp.com) plugin for [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org).

You can install it from https://github.com/ArtBIT/shutter-cloudapp-plugin